# Where does console.log info showup for Google Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I see the console.log prints when I'm running a Google Cloud function?  Is there a cloud console?

```
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
    res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
  } else {
    // Everything is okay.
    console.log(req.body.message);
    res.status(200).send('Success: ' + req.body.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Viewing Logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs)

You can view the Cloud Function logs using either:

- [The Stackdriver logging UI in the Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&_ga=1.139852922.87359700.1497482176)
- [Using logging API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_logging_api)

> ```
> // By default, the client will authenticate using the service account file
> // specified by the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable and use
> // the project specified by the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable. See
> // https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/latest/guides/authentication
> const Logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
>
> function getLogEntries () {
>   // Instantiates a client
>   const logging = Logging();
>
>   const options = {
>     pageSize: 10,
>     filter: 'resource.type="cloud_function"'
>   };
>
>   // Retrieve the latest Cloud Function log entries
>   // See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/logging
>   return logging.getEntries(options)
>     .then(([entries]) => {
>       console.log('Entries:');
>       entries.forEach((entry) => console.log(entry));
>       return entries;
>     });
> }
> ```

- [Using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_command-line_tool):

> To view logs with the gcloud tool, use the logs read command:
>
> ```
> gcloud functions logs read
> ```
>
> To view the logs for a specific function, provide the function name as
>   an argument:
>
> ```
> gcloud functions logs read <FUNCTION_NAME>
> ```
>
> You can even view the logs for a specific execution:
>
> ```
> gcloud functions logs read <FUNCTION_NAME> --execution-id EXECUTION_ID
> ```
>
> For the full range of log viewing options, view the help for logs
>   read:
>
> ```
> gcloud functions logs read -h
> ```

## [Writing Logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_logs)

You can use `console.log()` or `console.error()`.

- `console.log()` commands have the `INFO` log level.
- `console.error()` commands have the `ERROR` log level.
- Internal system messages have the `DEBUG` log level.

More info about viewing Cloud Function logs is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs).