# See continuous logging on command line

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working on a Firebase function. As I am still in the development stage, I have a number of logs in my code to see what's going on.

```
async function getAddressByIdAsync(address) {

    let addr = addressesRef.child(address);
    console.log(addr);

    return admin.database().ref('Addresses/' + address);
}
```

The only way I have found to be able to see these logs in real time is though the Firebase console, which is very slow and generally a bad UI experience IMO.

I'm looking for a command line solution that will let me see in real time the logs coming from the Firebase cloud function.

I have tried this command

```
firebase functions:log
```

Which appears to return the last twenty or so log entries into my Firebase Functions.

I know Google Cloud has a tail option on the end of that CLI but it doesn't work here.

```
firebase functions:log tail
```

> Error: Too many arguments. Run firebase help functions:log for usage instructions

Is there a way to get a live running output of the logs from firebase cloud functions?

Comment: What about using gcloud? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_command-line_tool. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556424/3371862

Comment: Can you use gcloud to hook to the firebase logs 

Comment: Firebase Cloud Functions logs are also available on the Google Cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the local emulator, that way you can first run your functions locally (and log in your terminal), before deploying.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: Im not sure the emulator will work since the only way i can call this is though the Google Home app as i am testing smart home device.